# PINESCRIPT - Lock ATR for Stop Loss and Take Profit

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I want to use ATR to take profit and set stop loss. The problem is, the ATR continues to adjust every bar. How do I set the ATR to be static number based on the opening candle and not continue to update every bar?

FYI: There are a few of this same question on stackoverflow, but none of them actually work.

I also have tried using strategy.position_avg_price instead of close but that never seems to work either.

Here is my code.

I am using v4.

Thanks!

```
// Create ATR
atr = atr(14)


// Determine stop loss price
longStopPrice  = close - (atr * 1)


// Take Profit
takeProfit = close + (atr *  1.5)
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Your stop loss and take profit points keep changing?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `strategy.position_size` to check if you have an open position and then place your take profit and stop loss levels with `strategy.exit`.

Here is a simple example:

```
//@version=5
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100)

longCondition = ta.atr(14) >= 100
tp = close * 1.01
plot(tp)

if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry(id="Long Id", direction=strategy.long)

if (strategy.position_size > 0)
    strategy.exit(id="Short Id", from_entry="Long Id", profit=tp)
```

[image]

Blue line is the take profit level calculated each bar. As you can see, take profit level changes every bar, however, the actual strategy exit takes places based on the initially calculated take profit level.

Comment: Ok sure. But now the ATR isn't being calculated in the take profit, it's just a static calculation am I right? So it won't adjust based on different timeframes?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to give you an idea. You can include atr into your take profit calculations. Calculations will be based on your chart's timeframe if you are not using the `security()` function.

Answer (score 0):

was trying to figure out the same problem today
just found this on another post

ta.valuewhen(condition, source, occurrence)